# Solve for $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^{\ln(x)}}{(\ln(x))^x}$

Tags: limits, infinity, limits-without-lhopital

> Solve for
>   $$
> \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^{\ln(x)}}{(\ln(x))^x}
> $$

I used l'Hôpital's rule but in vain. Could you help me someway. Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{   x^{\ln(x)}}{  (\ln(x))^x  }$ be your function.

If we take logarithm, we get

$$g(x)=\ln(f(x))$$

$$=(\ln(x))^2-x\ln(\ln(x))$$

$$=x\left(\frac{(\ln(x))^2}{x}-\ln(\ln(x)\right)$$

when $x\to +\infty$, the power grows fastly than logarithm.

$$\implies \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{(\ln(x))^2}{x}=0$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to +\infty}g(x)=-\infty$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: prove $\dfrac{x^{\ln x}}{(\ln x)^x} < \dfrac{1}{x}$ and this implies the limit is $0$. To this end, we prove: $x^{1+\ln x} < (\ln x)^x\iff \ln x(1+\ln x) < x\ln(\ln x)$. This final inequality can be established by taking derivative of the difference of LHS and RHS, and is left for you to try out. I think it should work.

Comment: i think L'Hospital is the right way, $0$ is the searched limit

Comment: Can we convert this limit, $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\cfrac{x^{lnx}}{(lnx)^x}$ to another limit like something $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\cfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

Comment: I want to use "$ln(x+1)$ is asymptotic to $x$ near $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using continuity of exponential and logarithm we have:
$$
\lim_{x\to + \infty}\frac{x^{\ln x}}{\ln^x x}= \exp\left[\ln\left(\lim_{x\to + \infty}\frac{x^{\ln x}}{\ln^x x} \right) \right]=
$$
$$
=\exp\left[\lim_{x\to + \infty}\left(\ln^2 x-x \ln(\ln x) \right)  \right]
$$
Now it is not difficult to show that the limit in the square brakets is $-\infty$